# Error in mysql syntax;

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
    Try

        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = " INSERT INTO billing ( BillingId, PatientId, bTotal, Cashtendered, Change, bStatus, Date, bTime ) VALUES ( '" & billingid.Text & "' , '" & Label5.Text & "' , '" & Label13.Text & "' , '" & ctt.Text & "' , '" & changelb.Text & "' , '" & Label16.Text & "' , '" & lbdate.Text & "' , '" & lbtime.Text & "' ) "

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Patient Saved")




        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'Change, bStatus, Date, bTime ) VALUES ('1', '1', '500','987','487','Paid' at line 1

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Firstly, you should probably not use quotes around e.g. integer types, e.g. `'" & billingid.Text & "'` (remove the single outer quotes). Secondly: for the love of God, step away from the keyboard and google about SQL injections. You are putting a neon sign above your website that says, please hack me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the errors I see

1. Change is a reserved keyword in mysql. Try using escaping it inside `` like

```
`change`
```

2. Date is also a reserved key word. look out for that  too.
3. Never post username/password with your code.
4. Use parameterised query as much as possible as a prevention from sql injections.